keepalived not starting after Upgrading Ubuntu from from 18.04LTS 20.04.6 LTS
I just recently upgraded my secondary load balancer to Ubuntu 20.04. However, keepalived service stopped working. Here are the logs when I try to stop, start and check the status of service :
root@xxxxx:/etc/keepalived# systemctl stop keepalived
root@xxxxx:/etc/keepalived# systemctl start keepalived
root@xxxxx:/etc/keepalived# systemctl status keepalived
● keepalived.service - Keepalive Daemon (LVS and VRRP)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-12-12 14:05:38 NZDT; 2s ago
    Process: 3047 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3047 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx systemd[1]: Started Keepalive Daemon (LVS and VRRP).
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Starting Keepalived v2.0.19 (10/19,2019)
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: WARNING - keepalived was build for newer Linux 5.4.166, running on Linux 5.4.0-200-generic #220-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 27 13:19:16 UTC 2024
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx systemd[1]: keepalived.service: Succeeded.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Command line: '/usr/sbin/keepalived' '--dont-fork'
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=3048
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Keepalived_vrrp exited with permanent error CONFIG. Terminating
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Stopped Keepalived v2.0.19 (10/19,2019)

From the syslogs:

Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=3048
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: WARNING - default user 'keepalived_script' for script execution does not exist - please create.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: (Line 70) Default interface eth0 doesn't exist for static address 10.xxx.x.10/24.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: (Line 71) Default interface eth0 doesn't exist for static address 10.xxx.x.11/24.
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: Non-existent interface specified in configuration
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived_vrrp[3048]: Stopped
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Keepalived_vrrp exited with permanent error CONFIG. Terminating
Dec 12 14:05:38 xxxxx Keepalived[3047]: Stopped Keepalived v2.0.19 (10/19,2019)

The only interface we have is ens192 and its configured as that in /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf, eth0 is not in the file.
Here the link of the interface which is up:
root@xxxxx:/etc/keepalived# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:01:01:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
